# what is the Best approach - Single Table Inheritance or Multiple class table inheritance in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord

what is the Best approach between Single Table Inheritance and Multiple class table inheritance in Rails?
When to use them and what are the consequence of using each?

Comment: "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Answer (score 1):

Use MTI when :

- Your models physically follow inheritance (***you should NOT use it
  otherwise***)
- Your models have plenty common attributes but at the same time plenty
  uncommon. If it is not the case, you should probably have them    in
  the same table (use STI)